# Have there been any improvements to ARKit Remote in Arkit 1.5?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

Have there been any improvements to ARKit Remote in Arkit 1.5?  The inability to register touch inputs on the device renders the remote basically useless for my team.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/arkit/ Here you got "What's new in ARKit 1.5"

Comment: ARKit Remote is a Unity feature, not an ARKit feature.

Comment: Unity has a plugin for ARKit.https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/unity-arkit-plugin-92515.  this would be the plugin im referring to.  which they just upgraded to catch up to ARKit native 1.5